# Some Kubeflow related questions

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I have some questions related to Kubeflow. Please take your time to answer these. Thanks.
Note: I am using a google cloud VM to run Kubernetes and Kubeflow.
Questions:

1. For a pipeline with 5 images/functions, can I send it to different resources? -> Function 1 to CPU1, Function 2 to CPU2, Function 3-5 to GPU?
2. If there are more jobs / tasks than resources, what happens? Is there a queue?
3. How do I monitor the total resources used in Kubeflow? Provide some of the best dashboard names.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: using microk8s=1.20 stable